# detect mime/extension of a file

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that when a user picks a file it can tell them whether it is a jpg, wav or another type (any other type goes under html). I got stuck in trying to process whether it is any of those types.

```
def openSoundOrPicture():
  file=pickAFile()
  print file
  print len(file)
  start=file.rfind('.')
  print start
  if start !=-1:
```

This is what I have so far but it doesn't work. (By the way, I'm really new to Python or any coding for the matter fact)

```
def openSoundOrPicture():
  file=pickAFile()
  print file
  ln=len(file)
  print ln
  start=file.rfind('.')
  print start
  if start !=-1:
   if file[start:ln]==".jpg"
     print "File type:jpg"
   elif file[start:ln]==".wav"
     print "File type:wav"
```

Comment: do a slice with start like `file[start:]` to get that extension into a separate string then compare accordingly

Comment: Take a look at the [`mimetypes` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html), which can give you a file type given a filename. Otherwise, there is the [`os.path.splitext()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext), returning the base filename, and its extension, as separate strings.

Comment: @RNar: why? What's wrong with `os.path.splitext()`, which splits of the extension for you?

Comment: @MartijnPieters different approaches, same value. I figured that since OP already got the index, might as well use it and it avoids an external import (though I doubt he is't already using `os` if he is working with files)

Comment: This is what I have done so far

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to categorize files by their extension.  Realize that there are other ways to do this like [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number).  However, for what you asked to do, check out this code snippet:

```
recognized_types = ["jpg", "wav"]
default_type = "html"

file = pick_a_file()
file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)
if file_extension in recognized_types:
    print "File Type: " + file_extension
else:
    print "File Type: " + default_type
```